# Error alta de usuario desde fuera de Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, seguridad, jboss, keycloak

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear un usuario en Keycloak realizando una llamada desde fuera de Keycloak. He creado un microservicios que al darle los datos te creara un usuario en Keycloak. No veo de donde viene el problema y llevo varios dias dando vueltas para encontrar una solución.

he probado añadiendo la dependencia resteasy-jackson2-provider pero me aparece el siguiente error " java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter"

```
       Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() //
               .serverUrl("http://localhost:8070/auth/") //
               .realm("realmnuevo") //
               .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD) //
               .clientId("clienteRealm") //
               .clientSecret("PIZKUIZcjK3aA2Xc07MxY1usULcmQJD1") //
               .username("manager") //
               .password("Pa55w0rd") //
               .build();
```

Error que se me genera:

```
2022-11-23 09:08:47.112  WARN 15701 --- [nio-8084-exec-2] org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n   : RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider from jar:file:/home/xxx/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider/3.13.2.Final/resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.13.2.Final.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/microprofile/config/ResteasyConfigFactory
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.getProperty(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:359) ~[resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.<clinit>(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:56) ~[resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.13.2.Final.jar:3.13.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:236) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.1.3.Final.jar:3.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2023) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.1.3.Final.jar:3.1.3.Final]
```

Pom.xml

```
dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Segun el error que muestras las clases faltantes están en las siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```